# How to enter multiple arguments in the interactive math mode

Tags: macros, lyx, arguments

I've defined a new command in the document's preamble. For the sake of this question the following (tested!) example:

```
\newcommand{\multipleargs}[3]{{#1}-{#2}-{#3}}
```

Using [cmd]-M on MacOS I want to be able to enter:

```
\multipleargs{A}{B}{C}
```

But when I try this, LyX only provides me with a "hole" for the first argument. Adding braces myself only results in "text" rather than passing the enclosed text as arguments.

And, yes, I know I can use the TeX-mode ([cmd]-L on MacOS) and type

```
$\multipleargs{A}{B}{C}$
```

But this question is about using commands with multiple arguments in the formula editor.

I don't want to use the LyX macro system because I want to collect these command later in my own style.

Please don't provide an alternative to `\multipleargs`, it is just a silly example to illustrate the *formula editing* question ;-)

Comment: Typing `\{` in the math mode works for me. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @scottkosty, Thanks! I had no clue it would be that simple.  Please make it an answer instead of a comment, so I can give it a thumbs up and increase your reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to tell LyX that you want to enter a literal `{`, you must enter a backslash before. So you should enter the two-character sequence `\{`. An alternative is to paste the full string `\multipleargs{A}{B}{C}` (with all args) into a math inset all at once.

It is ironic that entering `{` leads to the LaTeX `\{` and entering `\{` leads to the LaTeX `{`.

Comment: Precisely that irony threw me off ;-)  Thanks again!